# Using Bit Mask of 32 bits for a string

Tags: bitmask

Is there any simple function that can be used in the server which can bit mask ( 32 Bit) a hexadecimal or normal character string?

For example: If I have a string called 'Apple'. Can I bit mask it (32 bit) ? What should be the approach?

Comment: `that can be used in the server` What type of server? Chances are you're running x86 with an ASCII character set, so that would be supported natively in hardware, but the existence of a function assumes the existence of a structured language, so I must assume you're not writing machine code. Also, you probably don't need a function; most languages have an operator defined for bitwise operations like `&` and `|`.

Comment: More succinctly... What language are you programming in?

Comment: Any block of bits can be masked.  Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do?  Also, 'Apple' is 40 bits (in ASCII), so it's unclear what you're expecting.

Comment: I am trying to do this in Java..I have a list of some features which I would like to mask and send it across to the client side. I would like to know the best possible way to do this.